# Web Scraping Authorization required

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape https://gomechanic.in/gurgaon/car-repair/hyundai-creta/petrol this website. I want price of each service. In network, I also got the API which is giving all the data.  The API has the name get-service-detials-by-category. API Link: https://gomechanic.app/api/v2/oauth/customer/get-services-details-by-category?car_id=135&city_id=1&category_id=0&user_car_id=null . You can see this link in network section of inspect element. But when I am calling it in python, it is showing login required. But data is visible in response section.

My Python code:

```
url = "https://gomechanic.app/api/v2/oauth/customer/get-services-details-by-category?car_id=135&city_id=1&category_id=0&user_car_id=null"
header = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiNGJjM2NhZjVkMWVhOTlkYzk2YjQzM2NjYzQzMDI0ZTAyM2I0MGM2YjQ5ZjExN2JjMDk5OGY2MWU3ZDI1ZjM2MTU1YWU5ZDIxNjE2ZTc5NSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W10sInN1YiI6IjE2MzM5MTcwNjIzOSIsImV4cCI6MTYzNjUwOTA2Mi4wLCJhdWQiOiIzIiwibmJmIjoxNjMzOTE3MDYyLjAsImlhdCI6MTYzMzkxNzA2Mi4wfQ.IUP_RJVt6mqC5EMO3HKd-2iX69_dSgBEE-jJ0pg26bizK5EBvf48d0ZRiAcwPX6bNWAIkxH7hfqA0Zq0pu1SymyeDVpxmOB2D7H5t7aj1DqhgawxD7ZgoY6Q_nyA1SAmltbeFSAIf2mwVlQV4H-pdH74qiaIG1ij9kRsBpdLxSMqpas1Vy9mQN_8W5csu24gIjvPYAdaT6w6qxjCxrlbT24EJ0hswPCy4_h12AlpZKYs_oVAqHMKgVcyi9jSeXOS_KD8Kwbcx1hNVtYVblBg5xcezm8RtP8tcJ4XgHoqXWEmI349SEb1s8wZX4u1LtEKNovMWkBwWQr8_jBPNSy7rDRHnNAvT5h2u-x-1AlnN-JFLLsz9rCWLRoypG-_1-1Y46lOUAFgjVB1L4IvPJ3zk1dxjDNJPtxzV3e-GJWVv5qlHw3g3cTlTd05r4ab-PDj314K4Ft7P9RaLdgtrcdrpO_bbs00BBN7Vo87dPFL_NHl37FmWvsh6pQ1rCa6bkQKpCZTFxgcriKTjwYeeC2XLKpnJm26PQ5ALIQQIq4EEE2LZq7N8jZ-FEtg5ozTmQ9HxkZbG12LTZzbD472OmuuSDxRlWzyTF4ObMs0PyA8dyVRTYtYT8l1juxc71TRPzG_cnTVrbjCI-rbCqvvFokGosoC_VJdiQlt3Dau6t1IrmY",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "gomechanic.app",
    "Origin": "https://gomechanic.in",
    "Referer": "https://gomechanic.in/",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36"
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Note: The Authorization key keeps on changing so please update it before running the code. You can find it in header section of inspect element.

Screenshots for reference: [image: Data I need][image: Error I am getting]

I want all the the data of response section

Comment: Could you expand more on this? Your code is working fine. What results are you getting and what results are you expecting? Maybe the token just becomes expired by the time you use it?

Comment: Could it be that your IP is being banned?

Comment: @Granitosaurus I have added screenshots for your reference. Regarding IP ban, I don't think so because other APIs are working fine of the same website which doesn't require headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already getting the correct output at `page = requests.get(url, headers=header)` and you are printing output of `response = requests.get(url)` where you are not passing header. Also authorization key does not change here.

You can use the following code to get package and price.

```
op={}
page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
for d in page.json().get("data"):
    for service in d.get("services"):
        for package in service.get("package_details"):
                op[service.get("name")]=package.get("total")
print(op)
```

output:

```
{'Basic Service': 3199, 'Standard Service': 4199, 'Comprehensive Service': 5499}
```

Comment: And just one off topic question, how do you know authorization key will not change here?

Comment: @mukuldhiman Because authorization key is generally base64 encoded username and password or an API key. I highly doubt that every time a person refreshes a page, a new user id would be generated.